# Pivot tables in R - is there anyway to format the numbers with big marks and small marks?

Tags: r, shiny, format, pivot-table, shinyapps

I have a pivot table that has a variety or numbers ranging from small decimals to numbers in the millions. I want to add formatting like big mark and little mark in order to make the numbers more readable. Any suggestions?

```
    output$extPt <- renderPivottabler({
    name <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
    shortcut <- c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg')
    counter <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    temp <- data.frame(name, counter)

        extPt <- PivotTable$new()
        extPt$addData(temp)
        extPt$addColumnDataGroups("name")
        extPt$addRowDataGroups("counter")
        extPt$addRowDataGroups("shortcut")
        extPt$evaluatePivot()
        pivottabler(extPt)



     extPt$defineCalculation(calculationName = "SumOfCounter", caption = "Sum of Counter", 
      summariseExpression = "sum(counter, na.rm=TRUE)", format  = "%.2f")
    })
```

Something that can look like:

1, 235, 674.05

and 
0.12

and 
365, 222, 524.11

... etc

Comment: Try `format` function or the package `formattable`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work with pivot tables

Answer (score 0):

Try using `format()` in your summarize expression.

```
summariseExpression = "format(sum(counter, na.rm=TRUE), big.mark=',')"
```